# Using vectors to solve the anagrams in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that takes in two vectors of strings and compares each element to see if they are anagrams of one another.

**Vector #1:** "bat", "add", "zyz", "aaa"

**Vector #2:** "tab", "dad", "xyx", "bbb"

**Restrictions and other things to clarify:** The function is supposed to loop through both vectors and compare the strings. I am only supposed to compare based on the index of each vector; meaning I only compare the strings which are in the first index, then the strings which are in the second index, and so on. It's safe to assume that the vectors passed in as parameters will always be the same size.

If the compared strings are anagrams, "Match" is printed on the screen. If they aren't, "No Match" is printed.

*Output:* Match Match No Match No Match

I'm getting ridiculously stuck on this problem, I know how to reverse strings but when it gets to this I'm getting a bit clueless.

I understand that I would need to iterate through each vector, and then compare. But how would I be able to compare each letter within the string? Also, I'm not allowed to include anything else like algorithm, sort, or set. I've tried digging through a lot of questions but most answers utilized this.

If there are any tips on how to solve this, that would be great. I'll be posting what I find shortly.

Here's what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void anagrams(const vector<string>& vOne, const vector<string>& vTwo){
for(int i=0; i< vOne.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j< vTwo.size(); j++){
        if(vOne[i].size() != vTwo[j].size()){
            cout << 0 << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << 1 << endl;
        }
    }
  }
}
void quicksort(vector<int>& a, int low, int high){
    if(low < high)
    {
        int mid = (low + high)/2;
        int pivot = a[mid];
        swap(a[high], a[mid]);

        int i, j;

        for(i=low, j=high-1; ;){
            while(a[i]<pivot) ++i;
            while(j>i && pivot < a[j]) --j;
            if (i < j)
                swap(a[i++], a[j--]);
            else
                break;
        }

        swap(a[i], a[high]);
    } 
    quicksort(a, low, i - 1);
    quicksort(a, i + 1, high);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are only allowed to use vector and string?  Are there any other restrictions?

Comment: You're only allowed to use a vector of strings. As far as my understanding goes, there aren't any other restrictions. I just can't take any shortcuts. I only get to include the iostream, vector, and string packages.

Comment: Finding out if two strings are anagrams of each other is easy... a bit of lateral thinking reveals an obvious answer.  But your description of the problem is confusing.  If one vector has "bat" and "fruit" in it, and the other has "sherbert", "tab", and "spaghetti" in it, is your function going to say they match?  Going to print "bat" out and say it matches?  Going to find all of the words in one that are anagrams in the other?  (or are these really vectors of char's forming a string?)

Comment: Does each vector contain something like "b","a","t"?  My initial impression is that the vector contains the characters of the word (although each character is stored as a string).

Comment: http://ideone.com/ZURlFC

Comment: Walters, sorry about that. I'll try my best to clarify it. If one vector has "bat" and "fruit" in it, and the other vector has "sherbert", "tab", and "spaghetti" in it, my function is going to simply print "No Match" "No Match". What's happening is that it compares the strings based on their position in the vector. Meaning, the strings which are considered the first element in the vector are compared, then the second element, and so on.

To make it even clearer (and easier), we can assume that the vectors will always be the same size.

Comment: for an anargram, the order of letters is irrelevant. therefore, one of the way to detect if they are anargrams or not is, sorting two string content and compare the string. if same, then it is an anargram

Comment: So the strings will only contain characters between a-z and A-Z?

Comment: Smith_61 they will only be a-z, not A-Z.

Answer (score 2):

Though you are not able to use sort, you should still sort the the words you are checking against, to see if they are anagrams. You will just have to sort the char[] manually, which is unfortunate, yet a good exercise. I would make a predicate, a function that compares the 2 strings and return true or false, and use that to check if they are anagrams. Also, it seems as though you don't need to print out both words that actually match, if that is true, then you can sort the words in the vectors when you first read them in, then just run them through your predicate function.

```
// Predicate
bool isMatch(const string &lhs, const string &rhs)
{
    ...sort and return lhs == rhs;
}
```

If you write the function, as I have above, you are passing in the parameters by const reference, which then you can copy (not using strcpy() due to vulnerabilities) the parameters into char[] and sort the words. I would recommend writing your sort as its own function.
Another hint, remember that things are much faster, and stl uses smart ptrs to do sorting. Anyway, I hope this helps even a little bit, I didn't want to give you the answer.

Comment: I won't have to include anything else? All I'm allowed to include is the basics like iostream, vector, and string.

Thank you though! I appreciate the hints and not spoiling me with the answer.

Comment: `bool stringCompare( const string &left, const string &right ){
   for( string::const_iterator lit = left.begin(), rit = right.begin(); lit != left.end() && rit != right.end(); ++lit, ++rit )
      if( tolower( *lit ) < tolower( *rit ) )
         return true;
      else if( tolower( *lit ) > tolower( *rit ) )
         return false;
   if( left.size() < right.size() )
      return true;
   return false;
}`

how about something like that?

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is fairly quick as long as the strings only contain characters between a-z and A-Z would be

```
bool is_anagram( const string& s1, const string& s2 ) {
    if( s1.size() != s2.size() ) {
        return false;
    }

    size_t count[ 26 * 2 ] = { 0 };

    for( size_t i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++ ) {
        char c1 = s1[ i ];
        char c2 = s2[ i ];

        if( c1 >= 'a' ) {
            count[ c1 - 'a' ]++;
        }
        else {
             count[ c1 - 'A' + 26 ]++;
        }

        if( c2 >= 'a' ) {
            count[ c2 - 'a' ]--;
        }
        else {
             count[ c2 - 'A' + 26 ]--;
        }
    }
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 26 * 2; i++ ) {
        if( count[ i ] != 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use C++11, here is some rather inefficient code for seeing if two strings are anagrams.  I'll leave it up to you to loop through the list of words.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int count_occurrences(string& word, char search) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char s : word) {
        if (s == search) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

bool compare_strings(string word1, string v2) {       
    if (word1.size() != v2.size())
    {
        return false;
    }    
    for (char s: word1) //In case v1 contains letters that are not in v2
    {
        if (count_occurrences(word1, s) != count_occurrences(v2, s))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }        

    return true;
}

int main() {
    string s1 = "bat";
    string s2 = "atb";

    bool result = compare_strings(s1, s2);

    if (result)
    {
        cout << "Match" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No match" << endl;
    }

}
```

This works by simply counting the number of times a given letter occurs in a string.  A better way to do this would be to sort the characters in the string alphabetically, and then compare the sorted strings to see if they are equal.  I'll leave it up to you to improve this.

Best wishes.

Comment: The second loop is unnecessary. If the strings are the same length, then there must be a character in word1 that has a different number of occurrences in string2 if they are not anagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, since I'm sufficiently bored:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int equiv_class(char c) {
   if ((c>='A')&&(c<='Z')) return c-'A';
   if ((c>='a')&&(c<='z')) return c-'a';
   return 27;
}

bool is_anagram(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
   if (a.size()!=b.size()) return false;
   int hist[26]={};
   int nz=0; // Non-zero histogram sum tally
   for (int i=0, e=a.size() ; i!=e ; ++i)
   {
      int aclass = equiv_class(a[i]);
      int bclass = equiv_class(b[i]);
      if (aclass<27) {
         switch (++hist[aclass]) {
         case 1: ++nz; break; // We were 0, now we're not--add
         case 0: --nz; break; // We were't, now we are--subtract
         // otherwise no change in nonzero count
         }
      }
      if (bclass<27) {
         switch (--hist[bclass]) {
         case -1: ++nz; break; // We were 0, now we're not--add
         case  0: --nz; break; // We weren't, now we are--subtract
         // otherwise no change in nonzero count
         }
      }
   }
   return 0==nz;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> v1{"elvis","coagulate","intoxicate","a frontal lobotomy"};
   std::vector<std::string> v2{"lives","catalogue","excitation","bottlein frontofme"};
   for (int i=0, e=(v1.size()==v2.size()?v1.size():0); i!=e; ++i) {
      if (is_anagram(v1[i],v2[i])) {
         std::cout << " Match";
      } else {
         std::cout << " No Match";
      }
   }
}
```